# Python MySQL Connector not connecting

Tags: python, mysql, discord, connector

I've currently been creating some Discord bots and I have some data stored in mysql, 2 tables that are under the same database.

Using the same example from the MySQL connector documentation for Python, cnx.is_connected returns as false and my "for loop" doesnt run or errors me saying im not using it in the correct order.

My code with the Discord bot and async (for reference since idk where my issue lies):

```
import mysql.connector
import asyncio
import discord

client = discord.Client()
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password=’password’',
                             host='IP',
                             database='creative role-play')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   if message.author == client.user:
       return

   SteamID = 0
   messagelower = message.content.lower()
   if messagelower.startswith("!verify"):
       steamidnum = int(message.content[message.content.index(" ") + 1:])
       query = ("SELECT steamid64, SteamID, CharName, TotalPlayTime FROM playerinfo, member_list "
               "WHERE steamid64 AND SteamID = %d") % (steamidnum)

       cursor.execute(query)
       print (cursor)
       if cnx.is_connected():
           print('sucessfull...Connected to MySQL database')

       for (steamid64, SteamID, CharName, TotalPlayTime) in cursor:
           print("{}, {}, {}".format(SteamID, CharName, TotalPlayTime))
           CharName = str(CharName)
           TotalPlayTime = int(TotalPlayTime)
           print (SteamID, "", steamid64)
           print ("confirm 1")
           if steamid64 == SteamID:
               ifrole = "has already been entered, please contact <@232233468094840832> if this is you"
               print ("confirm2")

           else:
               TotalPlayTime = int(TotalPlayTime)
               print (TotalPlayTime)
               if TotalPlayTime >= 86400:
                   ifrole = "has become a Member of Modern Role-Play"
                   role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name="Member")
                   await client.add_roles(message.author, role)

                   add = ("INSERT INTO member_list "
                            "(steamid64, discordname, charactername)"
                            "VALUES (%(steamid64)s, %(discordname)s, %(charactername)s)")
                   values = {"steamid64": SteamID,
                       "discordname": message.author.name,
                       "charactername": CharName,}
                   cursor.execute(add, values)
                   cnx.commit()
               else:
                   ifrole = "does not meet the time requirement of 24 hours to become a Member"

           msg = "Player %s has a Playtime of %d hour's and %s! (%s)".format(message) % (CharName, TotalPlayTime / 3600, ifrole, steamidnum)
           await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)



@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print('Logged in as')
   print(client.user.name)
   print(client.user.id)
   print('--Now Online--')

client.run('Token')
```

Sorry if you don't want the Discord.py stuff in there.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 password=’password’',
```

You have an extra quotation mark (soz if im late)

Comment: probably, gonna stop commenting now